# Parse Email Threads - Split content and blockquote in Google Apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am reading inbox emails using Google Apps script.

The problem I am facing is when I have a email chain for a inbox thread, that is a mail thread has more than one reply and I extract individual mails one by one last mail is the concatenation of all replies from the beginning of the mail chain and its a big string.

My requirement is to split the each mail and display in Google Sheet and I am unable to find a way to split the mail chain to individual emails.

I tried to split at a particular string "On" which is the beginning of the every mail but I think it will fail at some point when user use the same string at some point in the subject.

```
msg = GmailApp.getInboxThreads(0,500)[245].getMessages()[6].getPlainBody();
msg.split("On")
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

It is **recommended to utilize the method [`getBody()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-message#getBody())** instead of `getPlainBody()` for each [message](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-message). The HTML string obtained from `getBody()` provides a more structured format, making it easier to identify patterns within the content. Once the patterns have been identified<sup>1</sup>, the string can be split from the index obtained through a [Regex match](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec). The text can then be extracted from the HTML string using the [`XmlService.parse(String)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/xml-service/xml-service#parse(String))<sup>2</sup> and [`getText()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/xml-service/element#getText()) functions.

Additionally, it is worth considering the presence of a text marker (`-----Original Message-----`) that signifies the beginning of a blockquote section. If the requirement is to extract only from plain text, then splitting or slicing the content based on this text pattern could be the optimal approach.

1. For example, Gmail applies the `gmail_quote` CSS class to the blockquote, while Protonmail uses `protonmail_quote`

2. An important thing to notice is that XML is much more strict than HTML. And, as such, the HTML should be sanitized/formatted properly before being passed to `XmlService.parse`

---

#### [Working example:](https://gist.github.com/maiconandsilva/212332ad20ccb5450b7754610fcea281)

The script's most important components are the variables `SELECTORS` and `BLOCKQUOTE_TEXT_SELECTORS`, which store the patterns used to identify the starting line of a blockquote. The information used for pattern matching was obtained from [Protonmail's WebClient](https://github.com/ProtonMail/WebClients/blob/70354b6633ba9b9afde7fa61049368b97b7d4568/applications/mail/src/app/helpers/message/messageBlockquote.ts#L1) project (no code was copied).

This script should be adapted to one's own neeeds and used as a source of information. Do not consider it to be complete.

```js
// LICENSED UNDER THE MIT LICENSE. See full LICENSE https://gist.github.com/maiconandsilva/212332ad20ccb5450b7754610fcea281

const SELECTORS = [
  { tag: "\\w+", attr: { name: "class", value: "protonmail_quote" } },
  { tag: "\\w+", attr: { name: "class", value: "gmail_quote" } },
  { tag: "div", attr: { name: "class", value: "gmail_extra" } },
  { tag: "div", attr: { name: "class", value: "yahoo_quoted" } },
  { tag: "blockquote", attr: { name: "id", value: "iosymail" } },
  { tag: "\\w+", attr: { name: "id", value: "tutanota_quote" } },
  { tag: "\\w+", attr: { name: "id", value: "zmail_extra" } },
  { tag: "\\w+", attr: { name: "id", value: "skiff_quote" } },
  { tag: "blockquote", attr: { name: "data-skiff-mail", value: null } },
  { tag: "\\w+", attr: { name: "id", value: "divRplyFwdMsg" } },
  { tag: "div", attr: { name: "id", value: '3D"divRplyFwdMsg"' } },
  { tag: "hr", attr: { name: "id", value: "replySplit" } },
  { tag: "\\w+", attr: { name: "class", value: "moz-cite-prefix" } },
  { tag: "div", attr: { name: "id", value: "isForwardContent" } },
  { tag: "blockquote", attr: { name: "id", value: "isReplyContent" } },
  { tag: "div", attr: { name: "id", value: "mailcontent" } },
  { tag: "div", attr: { name: "id", value: "origbody" } },
  { tag: "div", attr: { name: "id", value: "reply139content" } },
  { tag: "blockquote", attr: { name: "id", value: "oriMsgHtmlSeperator" } },
  { tag: "blockquote", attr: { name: "type", value: "cite" } },
  { tag: "\\w+", attr: { name: "name", value: "quote" } },
];

const BLOCKQUOTE_TEXT_SELECTORS = [/^\s*-----Original Message-----\s*$/gm];
const NEW_LINE_REPLACEMENT = "&#xA;";
const DOCTYPE = `<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">`; // Replace this with proper HTML DOCTYPE declaration
const BR_TAG_REGEX = /<[^>]*br[^>]*>/gi;
const CLOSING_BLOCK_TAGS_REGEX = /(<\/[^>]*div|table|tr[^>]*>)/gi;
const DIV_ENCLOSING_BR_TAG_REGEX = /<[^>/]*div[^>]*>\s*<[^>]*br[^>]*\/?>\s*<\/[^>]*div[^>]*>/gi;
const BEGIN_SPACE_REGEX = /^\s+/;
const END_SPACE_REGEX = /\s+$/;
const TAGS_REGEX = /<[^>]*>/g;
const NEW_LINE_REGEX = /\s*(?:\n)\s*/g;
const STYLE_TAG_REGEX = /<\s*style\b[^>]*>.*?<\/\s*style\s*>/gi;
const HEAD_TAG_REGEX = /<\s*head\b[^>]*>.*?<\/\s*head\s*>/gi;
const SCRIPT_TAG_REGEX = /<\s*script\b[^>]*>(.*?)<\/\s*script\s*>/gmi;
const EXCLUDES = [ NEW_LINE_REGEX, STYLE_TAG_REGEX, HEAD_TAG_REGEX, SCRIPT_TAG_REGEX ];

const splitAt = (str, index) => [str.slice(0, index), str.slice(index)];

const formatHtml = (html) => html
    .replace(DIV_ENCLOSING_BR_TAG_REGEX, NEW_LINE_REPLACEMENT + NEW_LINE_REPLACEMENT) // Don't duplicate new lines
    .replace(BR_TAG_REGEX, NEW_LINE_REPLACEMENT)
    .replace(CLOSING_BLOCK_TAGS_REGEX, `$1${NEW_LINE_REPLACEMENT}`);

const sanitizeHtml = (html) => {
  for (let exclude of EXCLUDES) {
    html = html.replace(exclude, '');
  }
  return html;
}

const removeAllTags = (html) => html.replace(TAGS_REGEX, '');

const formatText = (text) => text.replace(BEGIN_SPACE_REGEX, '').replace(END_SPACE_REGEX, '');

const getTextFromHtml = (html) => {
  let xml = XmlService.parse(`${DOCTYPE}<root>${removeAllTags(sanitizeHtml(formatHtml(html)))}</root>`);
  // console.log(xml);
  return formatText(xml.getRootElement().getValue());
};

const splitBlockQuoteFromText = (text) => {
  for (let selector of BLOCKQUOTE_TEXT_SELECTORS) {
    let blockQuoteTextFound = selector.exec(text);
    if (blockQuoteTextFound !== null) {
      return splitAt(content, blockQuoteTextFound.index);
    }
  }
  return [text, ""];
};

const removeBlockQuoteSelectors = (blockquote) => {
  for (let selector of BLOCKQUOTE_TEXT_SELECTORS) {
    blockquote = blockquote.replace(selector, "");
  }
  return blockquote;
}

function locateBlockquote(msg) {
  let blockQuoteFound;

  for (let selector of SELECTORS) {
    let { tag, attr } = selector;
    let attributeValues = attr.value !== null ? `${attr.name}="?.*?${attr.value}.*?"?` : `${attr.name}`;
    // console.log(attributeValues);
    // e.g. ^.*?</?\w+[^>]*class="?.*?protonmail_quote.*?"?.*?>.*?$
    //      ^.*?</?\w+[^>]*class="?.*?gmail_quote.*?"?.*?>.*?$
    let regexBlockquote = new RegExp(`<\s*${tag}[^>]*?${attributeValues}.*?>`, "gm");
    blockQuoteFound = regexBlockquote.exec(msg);

    if (blockQuoteFound !== null) break;
  }
  // console.log("MATCH=" + blockQuoteFound);

  let contentHtml = msg, blockquoteHtml;

  if (blockQuoteFound !== null) {
    // console.log("MATCH INDEX="+blockQuoteFound.index);
    [contentHtml, blockquoteHtml] = splitAt(msg, blockQuoteFound.index);
  }
  return [contentHtml, blockquoteHtml];
}

const htmlToText = (contentHtml, blockquoteHtml) => {
  let content = getTextFromHtml(contentHtml);
  let blockquote;
  
  // console.log(blockquoteHtml)
  if (blockquoteHtml === undefined) {
    // There might be a blockquote on the content text
    // since no blockquote html pattern was found
    [content, blockquote] = splitBlockQuoteFromText(content);
  } else {
    blockquote = getTextFromHtml(blockquoteHtml);
    blockquote = removeBlockQuoteSelectors(blockquote);
  }
  // console.log(blockquote);
  return [content, blockquote];
}

function GMAIL_MESSAGES() {
  let thread = GmailApp.getInboxThreads()[1];
  for (let message of thread.getMessages()) {
    let html = message.getBody();
    // console.log(html);
    let [contentHtml, blockquoteHtml] = locateBlockquote(html);
    // console.log([contentHtml, blockquoteHtml]);
    console.log(htmlToText(contentHtml, blockquoteHtml)[0]);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be more complex than I imagined, I came up with this which is not a perfect solution but I believe is in improvement (comments on the code explain why)

```js
function byThread() {
  var msg = GmailApp.getInboxThreads(0,50)[20].getMessages();
  for(var i=0; i<msg.length; i++){
    Logger.log(msg[i].getPlainBody().split(" <")[0]) // the split happens at [blank space]< as I think this is a more uncommon character combination
  }
}
```

I then attempted a more reliable solution here:

```js
function byThreadv2() {
  var msg = GmailApp.getInboxThreads(0,50)[20].getMessages();
  const regExp = /On \w{3}, \w{3} \d{2}, \d{4} at [\d\:]{4,5} [AM|PM]* .* <.*@.*\..*>/
  // The regexp is looking for the "On <weekday>, <MMM DD>, <Year> at <time> AM <Person's name> <<Email Address>>" section of the emails 
  for(var i=0; i<msg.length; i++){
    var delimiter = regExp.exec(msg[i].getPlainBody()) //Using the regexp a delimiter is created for this email instance from the thread 
    Logger.log(msg[i].getPlainBody().split(delimiter)[0]) //Regexp result is used as a filter for split
  }
}
```

However I am still seeing some other threads there, I suspect is because of the way my emails are written (as they have some special sequence of characters but could you please test and let me know if this works for you?

Comment: Thank you very much for the solution, will test and let you know tomorrow

Comment: Thanks for the solution, unfortunately solution is not working as I am getting error at `msg[i].getPlainBody()` where error says `its not a function`, when I removed getPlainBody, able to get some result but email is split for every character,  Can you please let me know if you have any alternate solution.

Comment: @Siva: a good rule of thumb when receiving answers here is not to use them unquestioningly, but to use the new code as a jumping-off point for your own ideas. How would you fix it? It can be assumed that `.getPlainBody()` is a method on a particular class, so perhaps the value at `msg[i]` is of the wrong class, or maybe it is null. Can you find out what type is at that index, and why it is of an unexpected type?